# How can I create a new postgreSQL database while already inside of a database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My postgreSQL configuration is a bit messed up, and I currently need to login to a database using the command `psql -U myUsername myDbName`. I only have one database that I created with that username, so I always login to that database. Is there a way that I can create a new database while within another database?

I tried the command `CREATE DATABASE dbname;` while within the database but that didn't work.

Comment: What error message did you get? If you have sufficient privileges, `create database dbname;` should work in both psql and in pgadminIII.

Comment: `ERROR:  permission denied to create database`

Comment: That just answered your own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, the error `ERROR: permission denied to create database` indicates that the "Not every user has authorization to create new databases. If PostgreSQL refuses to create databases for you then the site administrator needs to grant you permission to create databases. Consult your site administrator if this occurs. If you installed PostgreSQL yourself then you should log in for the purposes of this tutorial under the user account that you started the server as." - [pgDocs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/tutorial-createdb.html)

Thus, in order to access the postgres admin I had to change my `pg_hba.conf`

from:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

to:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

and then run the following in the command prompt:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Grant "myUsername" user permissions to create databases i.e:
    ALTER ROLE myUsername CREATEROLE CREATEDB;

source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html